# Issue with IPv6 on Samba share when connecting from Windows clients - a Windows Credentials box appears asking for username and password

Tags: linux, networking, samba, ipv6

If I remove IPv6 from Linux Samba shares are accessible again - reinstate IPv6 - dialog box for credentials appears again.

Has anyone got any ideas?